# Can I download all the files under File app without copying them on iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, files.app

I want to download locally all the files under a directory in the File app on iPhone, but there seems to be no option but selecting all the files and copy them.

However, I want to just download all of the files locally, especially because sometimes the files are automatically deleted for some reasons and I must copy them again whenever it happens.

The files are put under iCloud and I put these files from my Mac.